Is there a way to get the value from Slide bar (Scale) after releasing the mouse button in Tkinter?
I am trying to get only the last value after using the slice bar with Tkinter but I am getting all intermediate values too. I am trying to use a linear stage with Tkinter and it is a problem if it tries to set all intermediate positions until it gets to the final value.
This is my code:
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, serial):
        super().__init__()

        self.serial = serial

        self.button = Button(text="Home", command=self.serial.home)
        self.button.pack()

        self.lin_stage = Scale(
            from_=0,
            to=self.serial.range[0],
            command=self.set_value,
            orient=HORIZONTAL,
            state="normal",
            relief="groove",
            activebackground="blue",
        )
        self.lin_stage.grab_release()
        self.lin_stage.pack()

    def handle_button_press(self):
        self.destroy()

    def set_value(self, val):
        val = float(val)
        print(val)
        # return self.serial.set_position(val, axis=0)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    woco = WOOPTIXController(port="COM3", baudrate=115200, n_axis=2)
    # Start the event loop.
    win = Window(woco)
    win.mainloop()



As it can be seen, the function prints all values until value 20 is reached. How can I get only the last one?

Have you tried binding to the <ButtonRelease> event of the scale?

Thanks a lot, that works!

Following  Bryan Oakley's comment I found the solution. Here is a ralated question: TkInter, slider: how to trigger the event only when the iteraction is complete?
And here is my solution, whre only the value after releasing the slider is printed:
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, serial):
        super().__init__()

        self.serial = serial

        self.button = Button(text="Home", command=self.serial.home)
        self.button.pack()

        self.lin_stage = Scale(
            from_=0,
            to=self.serial.range[0],
            orient=HORIZONTAL,
            state="normal",
            relief="groove",
            activebackground="blue",
        )
        self.lin_stage.bind(
            "<ButtonRelease>",
            self.set_value,
        )
        self.lin_stage.pack()

        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.show = Button(self.frame, text="Show")

    def set_value(self):
        print(self.lin_stage.get())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    woco = WOOPTIXController(port="COM3", baudrate=115200, n_axis=2)
    # Start the event loop.
    win = Window(woco)
    win.mainloop()

